# How to relate a value to a name

Tags: sentence-construction, proper-nouns

I read:

> It may be preceded by **the heading INTRODUCTION**.

In this example "Introduction" comes immediately after "heading" and "heading" gets "the". Is it a common way to express such constructions?

what about

1. It may be preceded by the heading **of** INTRODUCTION.
2. It may be preceded by heading INTRODUCTION.
3. It may be preceded by **a** heading **labeled** INTRODUCTION.

Comment: What you originally read is the most natural form - all of your alternatives sound clumsy. Bear in mind that for most purposes, a "heading" ***is*** the text itself that constitutes the heading. If you talk about "labeling" different headings, that implies identifying them as *Heading **A**, Heading **B**, etc.* Which might be relevant to a programmer or typesetter, but it's unlikely to suit your context.

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts, you can use quotations marks to set off the thing being named:

> It may be preceded by the heading "INTRODUCTION."

(Your readers will understand that the heading itself will not include quotation marks.)

As for the article "the," the answer is "Yes." However they may choose to set off the thing being named, English speakers commonly use the definite article when naming a thing in this way, e.g.:

> The play "Hamilton."
>   The language **Esperanto.**
>   The baseball team called *The Cubs.*

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you understand the word **preceded**?
2. Do you understand the above question?

My rhetorical question #1 uses “the word **preceded**”
in exactly the same sense as “the heading INTRODUCTION” in your example. 
I would say that this is a *somewhat* common way to express such constructions. 
A couple of comparable examples:

> The class was led by their teacher, Bob.

and

> All day long I look forward to my favorite class, Math.

It is generally very useful (if not necessary)
to provide some sort of separation between the generic, descriptive word
and the specific name/title/value/labels. 
Your example capitalizes the title “INTRODUCTION”,
@P. E. Dant suggests using quotation marks,
my first example uses a font change, and my other examples use commas. 
I’m struggling (without success) to think of an example
that’s easily understandable without any demarcation. 
@FF suggests that this flows most easily when you’re writing about words.